# random message every x seconds but to stay on screen for a few seconds

Tags: random, timer, processing, milliseconds

I have a program where I am displaying a message every x seconds (the message pops up), is there a way for the message to stay a little bit on the screen, because there is no time for the user to read it properly.

your guidance is much appreciated.

below is a piece of my code where I am using millis().

```
if (millis() - timer >= 4000) //random message every 4 seconds
      {
        if(user11.equals(rev_film1[0]))
        {
          app.text(user11, 15,490);
          app.text(rat_film1[0] + " / 10",100,550);
          timer = millis();
        }
        else if(user11.equals(rev_film1[1]))
        {
          app.text(user11, 15,490);
          app.text(rat_film1[1] + " / 10",100,550);
          timer = millis();
        }
        else if(user11.equals(rev_film1[2]))
        {
          app.text(user11, 15,490);
          app.text(rat_film1[2] + " / 10",100,550);
          timer = millis();
        }
        else if(user11.equals(rev_film1[3]))
        {
          app.text(user11, 15,490);
          app.text(rat_film1[3] + " / 10",100,550);
          timer = millis();
        }
      }
```

Comment: Anyway, now you have timer for showing text. You also need timer for hiding text, I suppose.

Comment: I am using processing as my framework, should I create another timer then ?

Comment: New timer, or r re-use the same timer and use some other mechanism to distinguish what you should do when timer expires. Maybe. I'm not familiar with *procesing*.

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: It may not be important, bit what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about how **you** would know when to show and hide the square. What is the value of `timer` when you want to show and hide the square? What is the value of `millis()`?

Write out a few examples of timelines, something like this:

```
millis = 0: program start
millis >= 4000: show message
millis >= 6000: hide message
```

Then use this timeline as a guide for when you want stuff to happen, and map this to the variables in your sketch.

If you're having trouble, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (not your entire sketch, but not a disconnected snippet either) in a new question post and we'll go from there. Good luck.